# Symbolicated Crash Log: Is this How I Follow Offsets?

Tags: ios, swift, debugging, crash, app-store-connect

I'm very new to the App Store Validation process, and I'm getting a crashes in their testing that do not happen in Simulators or real device testing. This seems to be common story.

Here's the relevant part of the latest crash log from Apple:

```
Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   WordsBy2                        0x0000000102f757b0 0x102f68000 + 55216
1   WordsBy2                        0x0000000102f75698 0x102f68000 + 54936
2   WordsBy2                        0x0000000102f79cbc 0x102f68000 + 72892
3   WordsBy2                        0x0000000102f753fc 0x102f68000 + 54268
4   UIKitCore                       0x0000000182eeb35c -[UIClassSwapper initWithCoder:] + 2196
5   UIFoundation                    0x0000000189618edc UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 696
6   UIFoundation                    0x00000001895a5854 -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 308
7   UIKitCore                       0x0000000182eef544 -[UIRuntimeConnection initWithCoder:] + 128
8   UIFoundation                    0x0000000189618edc UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 696
9   UIFoundation                    0x00000001896190f4 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 1232
10  UIFoundation                    0x00000001895a5854 -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 308
11  UIKitCore                       0x0000000182eea4fc -[NSCoder+ 7791868 (UIIBDependencyInjectionInternal) _decodeObjectsWithSourceSegueTemplate:creator:sender:forKey:] + 488
12  UIKitCore                       0x0000000182eeced4 -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1064
13  UIKitCore                       0x000000018341c948 -[UIStoryboard __reallyInstantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:creator:storyboardSegueTemplate:sender:] + 280
14  UIKitCore                       0x000000018341c7e4 -[UIStoryboard _instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:creator:storyboardSegueTemplate:sender:] + 124
15  UIKitCore                       0x000000018350c704 -[UIWindowScene _loadWindowWithStoryboardIfNeeded:] + 96
16  UIKitCore                       0x000000018350c670 -[UIWindowScene _readySceneForConnection] + 148
17  UIKitCore                       0x00000001827c69d0 +[UIScene _sceneForFBSScene:create:withSession:connectionOptions:] + 1012
18  UIKitCore                       0x00000001832abca0 -[UIApplication _connectUISceneFromFBSScene:transitionContext:] + 1032
19  UIKitCore                       0x00000001832ac044 -[UIApplication workspace:didCreateScene:withTransitionContext:completion:] + 328
20  UIKitCore                       0x0000000182debab8 -[UIApplicationSceneClientAgent scene:didInitializeWithEvent:completion:] + 360
21  FrontBoardServices              0x000000018fd69704 -[FBSScene _callOutQueue_agent_didCreateWithTransitionContext:completion:] + 404
22  FrontBoardServices              0x000000018fd91130 __94-[FBSWorkspaceScenesClient createWithSceneID:groupID:parameters:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke.176 + 100
23  FrontBoardServices              0x000000018fd76e60 -[FBSWorkspace _calloutQueue_executeCalloutFromSource:withBlock:] + 232
24  FrontBoardServices              0x000000018fd90e44 __94-[FBSWorkspaceScenesClient createWithSceneID:groupID:parameters:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke + 312
25  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000180678280 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
26  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018061d930 _dispatch_block_invoke_direct$VARIANT$mp + 224
27  FrontBoardServices              0x000000018fdb5e60 __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 40
28  FrontBoardServices              0x000000018fdb5b28 -[FBSSerialQueue _targetQueue_performNextIfPossible] + 404
29  FrontBoardServices              0x000000018fdb5ffc -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 28
30  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001809bfbf0 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24
31  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001809bfaf0 __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 204
32  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001809bee38 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 256
33  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001809b93e0 __CFRunLoopRun + 776
34  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001809b8ba0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 572
35  GraphicsServices                0x0000000197721598 GSEventRunModal + 160
36  UIKitCore                       0x00000001832aa2f4 -[UIApplication _run] + 1052
37  UIKitCore                       0x00000001832af874 UIApplicationMain + 164
38  libswiftUIKit.dylib             0x0000000194139b54 UIApplicationMain+ 80724 (_:_:_:_:) + 100
39  WordsBy2                        0x0000000102f6c9ec 0x102f68000 + 18924
40  libdyld.dylib                   0x0000000180697568 start + 4
```

This a fairly simple question, but I want to be sure... the last line corresponds to the start() method in my initialization process, and I presume the the + 4 is the fourth line of code in that code block? And I also presume that that includes commented lines in my original code?

If so, and that line sets a property of an optional instantiated class, then I assume a crash at this line would indicate that there was a problem with that object, but that the object would not appear in the crash log, since it wasn't one of its methods that was called. Correct?